# Replace all occurrences of a character in a variable using korn script

Tags: text-processing, shell-script, ksh, sql

Part of the Korn script I am writing requires that I replace all occurrences of the `'` character with two occurrences (`''`).  I am trying to log some SQL that I am generating in this script to a column in another table but single quotes need to be replaced with 2 instances of the single quote character.  I know there must be examples of this functionality somewhere but I'm not finding a string replace example specific to variables anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you couldn't call `sed` from within your `ksh` script?

This simple script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

foo="left ' right"
echo $foo
foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed "s#\'#\'\'#g")
echo $foo
```

gives me this output:

```
left ' right
left '' right
```

Comment: Always double quote variable substitutions. As written, this mangles whitespace and shell wildcard characters; that leaves ample holes for an attacker. @Ben **do not use this code, it's broken.** (I usually fix rather than downvote in such cases, but this is a question about quoting!)

Answer (score 7):

In ksh93 and zsh, there's a string replacement construct `${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}`, used twice in the following snippet: once to replace `'` by `''` and once to replace newlines by `'+char(10)+'`. If there are no newlines in the input string, you can omit the second assignment command.

```
quoted_string=\'${raw_string//\'/\'\'}\'
quoted_string=${quoted_string//$'\n'/"'+char(10)+'"}
```

This construct is also available in bash, but the quoting rules are different. The following snippet works in all of ksh93, bash and zsh.

```
quoted_string=\'${raw_string//$'\''/$'\'\''}\'
quoted_string=${quoted_string//$'\n'/$'\'+char(10)+\''}
```

In ksh88 and other shells, you need to write a relatively complex loop to replace the single quotes one at a time. The following snippet doubles single quotes, but leaves newlines unchanged).

```
q="$raw_string"; quoted_string=
while
    quoted_string="$quoted_string'${q%%\'*}'"
    case "$q" in *\'*) q="${q#*\'}";; *) false;; esac
do :; done
```

Alternatively, you can use sed. Be careful when feeding the data to sed, as `echo` doesn't always print its argument as-is.

```
quoted_string="'$(printf '%s\n' "$raw_string" |
                  sed -n -e "s/'/''/g" -e 'H' \
                      -e '$ g' -e 's/^\n//' -e "s/\\n/'+char(10)+'/g" -e '$ p')'"
```

If there are no newlines in the string, the following much simpler sed command suffices.

```
quoted_string="'$(printf '%s\n' "$raw_string" | sed -e "s/'/''/g")'"
```

Comment: +1. With the last example, I'm getting the warning "sed: Missing newline at end of file standard input." -- do you mean `printf "%s\n"` instead of `%s`?

Comment: @glenn Yes (I tested but with GNU sed which doesn't care about final newlines). Thanks for that; also your comment made me realize it would be a good idea to replace with newlines in the input string, even if this wasn't in Ben's question.